# How to skip validation in JSf in case of save draft form

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have two buttons in a form. One is submit button and another one is save draft button. I have a several components on the form for some of them I used regex validator. when I click on  submit button all regex validators are working and giving an error if any component failed. Now the problem is when I click on the save draft button then also all the validators are executing. How can I avoid that validators in case of click on submit draft. I tried with immediate true, but no help.

Comment: _"I tried with immediate true, but no help."_ Then you tried wrong... Please read [ask] and [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and improve your question.

Comment: If he uses ajax immediate is useless.

Comment: Please, post more code. Your issue is impossible to reproduce without a concrete example. @AlexFire, you assume the OP is using ajax (which haven't told) and also he has the ajax event tied to the button, and that he haven't declared a `process` attribute either. Too much to guess.

Comment: I don't assume anything, I've just said IF. However, it doesn't matter: you can't skip validation of a field you want to process and write back to your model with standard JSF means neither with immediate nor with ajax. You have to use a work around. Just search for "skip JSF validation" at SO.